# No bin/bundle file in Rails 6.1, can't get TURBO_STREAM request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

when I run
`rails turbo:install`
it gives `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - bin/bundle`

There is no bin/bundle file, in a new rails 6.1.3 app, with the turbo-rails gem (v0.5.9)

I don't know if this is related to the fact a request won't send as TURBO_STREAM, even when it is from a link inside a Turbo Frame.

Any clues how to troubleshoot?

---

UPDATE: I copied bin/bundle from a different app that is sending TURBO_STREAM formats, but it still sends only HTML in a new app (webpacker@^6.0.0-beta.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting the `turbo-rails` gem from `0.5.9` back to `0.5.3` fixed this

Actually, it seems TURBO_STREAM isn't always the request type any more, be design, but turbo frames still work.